# Angular removes directory in url when routing

Tags: angular

I set up a local IIS and a application with a directory called test:

[image]

Then in my browser I browse to: "http://localhost/test"

I have a route for this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { 
  path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent 
 },
 { 
  path: '**', redirectTo: '' 
 }
];

 @NgModule({
    imports: [
       RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
 })

 export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

But when I arrive at the login page, the browser removes the "test" and just does the "http://localhost/" in the browsers address, which is wrong.

The browser also don't get the assets now as "test" is missing:
[image]
Just for information, when I build the app, I build it with --baseHref=/test/

Comment: why you are browsing to http://localhost/test, you should browsing localhost only and your localhost should serve index.html. for assets base href will be used.

Comment: What you have should work. Maybe add `enableTracing: true` in your `forRoot` config and see if you can identify the problem

Comment: Please share your login component as well, maybe your login redirection needs to be change.

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: Have you tried updating your `deployUrl`?

Comment: Angular 9. I tried the deployurl.

Answer (score 1):

you set it to redirect to blank if there is no matching route, and there is not one for `test`...

guessing you want to set the base href in your build command...

```
ng build --prod --baseHref=test
```

docs: https://angular.io/cli/build

you can set the same in `ng serve` if you're trying to run this as a dev server. but that seems redundant.

Comment: Look at my last line, I am using baseHref

Answer (score 0):

Try directing through router class. After setting in component;
.navigate
to me it happend with wrong name.

Comment: can you share code?
this is not understandable, what exactly u want to say